# how to programmatically import places into Bing Maps (My places)

Tags: bing-maps

Is there a way to programmatically import favorite places (as kmk file format) into Bing maps(my places)?
I didn't find any api for that.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to programmatically upload data into the My Places function of the Bing Maps website.

If you want to do anything programmatically with Bing Maps, use the Bing Maps API's and not the website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx

You can upload your data into the Bing Spatial Data Services and then overlay that data on top of Bing Maps. Here is a good article to get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948092.aspx

Comment: I disagree with you, I did it to create a tool that imports Here Maps favorites to Bing Maps. (just a bit of reverse engineering on the web version and I quickly found how to programmatically import favorites)

Comment: This is a hack and against the terms of use of Bing Maps. So not something that should be recommended.

Comment: This guy didn't say what was his project, it could be for personal usage. Moreover, I gave my code to Microsoft so they can launch the same tool on Windows 10 Maps app, so why that shouldn't be recommended? It works fine. So please don't say `You won't be able` when we are actually able

Comment: Personal or professional, it is still against the terms of use. Also, by not being documented, it isn't supported, this can be disabled at any time. If they create a dependency on this code, their application would break without warning.

Comment: There are tons of reverse engineering questions and answers on "Stack websites" many of them are obviously against term of use. People answer to provide solution to a problem. Instead what you say is the same as _You see that door over there? This is the door to YOUR personal room where you can manipulate YOUR personal data. The door is unlocked but don't open it, because it's forbidden_ ... If this guy needs a one shot import to avoid the pain of doing it manually for hundreds of his favorite places well then I'm glad to show him the way..

Comment: sure, but if someone isn't asking specifically about reverse engineering, it shouldn't be recommended, at least not without clarifying the risks associated with it.